# ComException HRESULT: 0x800A03EC thrown when attempting to add Validation to a Range

Tags: c#, .net, excel

When trying to use the `Range.Validation.Add()` method, I'm consistently getting a very unfriendly error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Validation.Add(XlDVType Type, Object AlertStyle, Object Operator, Object Formula1, Object Formula2)
   at TravelPlannerTools.Sheet8.OperaCodesDropDown() in C:\Users\Michael Utz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TravelPlannerTools\TravelPlannerTools\Sheet8.cs:line 39
   at TravelPlannerTools.Sheet8.Sheet8_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Michael Utz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TravelPlannerTools\TravelPlannerTools\Sheet8.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetImpl.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetImpl.WorksheetExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetBase.OnStartup()
   at TravelPlannerTools.Sheet8.FinishInitialization() in C:\Users\Michael Utz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TravelPlannerTools\TravelPlannerTools\Sheet8.Designer.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
```

I am using the proper version of Excel and trying to perform a very simple task.

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Lann");
        list.Add("Latl");
        list.Add("LBBB");
        var flatList = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
        var cell = Globals.Sheet8.Cells.Range["A2"];
        cell.Validation.Delete();
        cell.Validation.Add(
            Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
            Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
            Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
            flatList,
            System.Type.Missing
            );
        cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
        cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The cell I was trying to write to was on a protected sheet. Using the `Worksheet.Protect()` and `Worksheet.Unprotect()` methods to toggle protection before and after the operation cleared up the error!